# Android HTTP Get response

Tags: java, android, http, get, response

I sent a GET message with socket. But unfortunately GET response isn't `200 OK` of status. Response is `400 Bad request` or `302 Found` or etc. How can I fix to this problem ? Can you help me ?

```
    String requestmsg = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    requestmsg += "User-Agent: MYCUSTOMAGENT\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Accept-Language: en-us\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Connection: close\r\n";
    requestmsg += "\r\n";

    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    BufferedReader dis = null;

    try {
        Log.d("ClientActivity", "Connecting...");
        String addr = InetAddress.getByName("www.facebook.com").getHostAddress().toString();
        Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 80);
        String data = "";

        try {
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            dos.write(requestmsg.getBytes());
            Log.i("ClientActivity", "RequestMsg Sent");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((data = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(data);
            }

            Log.i("ClientActivity", "C: Received " + sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);

        }
        socket.close();
        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
    }
```

Comment: The line `requestmsg += "text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n";` is not a valid header line. Unless you made a copying error while posting the question?

Comment: I have edited.Thank you. Is there any your idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `Host:` header, required for `HTTP/1.1` requests.

Comment: But I already sent to host with socket ( Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 80) ). Why host required for HTTL/1.1 ? Can be solving of my problem other reason ?

Comment: A socket connects to an IP address it gets when resolving the hostname, so the host information is lost on this layer. And because a server listening on an (IP, port) pair can serve multiple hosts, you need to provide that as a header. So you can have 1.2.3.4:80 serve `example.com`, `toys.com`, `bunnies.com`, but the socket only knows it connected to 1.2.3.4, not which host you are requesting. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Comment: I chanced my GET message but GET response is "HTTP/1.1 400 No Content-Type :text /htmlX-FB-Debug: .......bla bla " . My new GET request message is                                                                                               **String requestmsg = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
requestmsg += "User-Agent: MYCUSTOMAGENT\r\n";
requestmsg += "Host: www.facebook.com";
requestmsg += "Accept: */*\r\n";
requestmsg += "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
requestmsg += "\r\n";**